# spring3 jpa2.0 tomcat error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: com.web.emscs.entity.Student@1edf83b is not a known entity type

Tags: spring, jsf, jpa, tomcat7

I am trying to configure spring with eclipselink jpa but am facing the following error after given some data in UI and persist to database(oracle 10g).

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: com.web.emscs.entity.Student@1edf83b is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4128)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:406)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:358)
    at $Proxy16.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.web.daoimpl.StudentDAOImpl.saveStudent(StudentDAOImpl.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy9.saveStudent(Unknown Source)
    at com.web.serviceimpl.StudentServiceImpl.saveStudent(StudentServiceImpl.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy10.saveStudent(Unknown Source)
    at com.web.controller.EquipmentController.saveEquipment(EquipmentController.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my source,

EquipmentController.java

```
package com.web.emscs.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import com.web.emscs.entity.Student;
import com.web.emscs.service.StudentService;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class EquipmentController implements Serializable
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{StudentService}")
    StudentService studentService;
    private String sno;
    private String name;
    private String city;

    public String getSno() {
        return sno;
    }
    public void setSno(String sno) {
        this.sno = sno;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public StudentService getStudentService() {
        return studentService;
    }
    public void setStudentService(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }
    public void saveEquipment()
    {
        Student s=new Student();
        s.setSno(sno);
        s.setName(name);
        s.setCity(city);
        try
        {
            getStudentService().saveStudent(s);
            System.out.println("Saved");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    }

}
```

Student.java

```
package com.web.emscs.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable 
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String sno;
    private String name;
    private String city;
    public String getSno() {
        return sno;
    }
    public void setSno(String sno) {
        this.sno = sno;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) 
    {
        this.city = city;
    }


}
```

StudentDAOImpl.java

```
package com.web.emscs.daoimpl;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.web.emscs.dao.StudentDAO;
import com.web.emscs.entity.Student;

@Transactional
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO
{
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }



    public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }


    @Override
    public void saveStudent(Student student) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getEmf().createEntityManager().persist(student);
    }
}
```

StudentServiceImpl.java

```
package com.web.emscs.serviceimpl;

import com.web.emscs.dao.StudentDAO;
import com.web.emscs.entity.Student;
import com.web.emscs.service.StudentService;

public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService 
{
    StudentDAO studentDAO;

    public StudentDAO getStudentDAO() {
        return studentDAO;
    }

    public void setStudentDAO(StudentDAO studentDAO) {
        this.studentDAO = studentDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveStudent(Student student) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getStudentDAO().saveStudent(student);
    }


}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context.xsd
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd ">

    <!-- Database Configuration -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <import resource="springConfig.xml"/>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="EMCSSpring"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform"/>

    </bean>

</property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
    <property name="username" value="automobile"/>
    <property name="password" value="mobile"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="persistenceAnnotation" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

springConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="Student" class="com.web.emscs.entity.Student"></bean>

    <bean id="StudentService" class="com.web.emscs.serviceimpl.StudentServiceImpl">
        <property name="studentDAO" ref="StudentDAO" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="StudentDAO" class="com.web.emscs.daoimpl.StudentDAOImpl">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="EMCSSpring">
    <class>com.web.emscs.entity.Student</class>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE  "STUDENT" 
   (    "SNO" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(50), 
     CONSTRAINT "STUDENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SNO") ENABLE
   )
```

Let me have solution for this. what i have done wrong with this code.

Comment: Your question title is quite different from the exception message and therefore your question is confusing. The current answer of Ralph is based on your question title, but your stacktrace (which you initially posted unformatted, making it "unreadable"), points out a completely different class which you complained about in the answer's comments. What is it now?

Comment: anyone help me? i have altered my post title is it possible to clear my problem right now?

Comment: Let me have solution For this post still am having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Package of Student class in stacktrace (com.web.entity.Student) does not match to the source code (com.web.**emscs**.entity.Student). That means that running software was not compiled from the sources presented.

In shown code naming is uniform (`com.web.emscs.entity.Student`), so executing freshly compiled version will solve problem.

Comment: i have modified package and recompiled source right now its showing same error i cont realize this y its happening any one help me for this problem